# Parse datetime string in python ---> Fri Dec 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)

Tags: python-dateutil

**Trying this code snippet:-**

```py
from dateutil import parser as date_parser

print(date_parser.parse("Fri Dec 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)"))
```

**Getting this error:-**

```bash
raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)

dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Fri Dec 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT +0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove GMT, use +0530 instead of 0530 (without +) and IST instead of Indian Standard Time. Here's the code:

```py
from dateutil import parser as date_parser

print(date_parser.parse("Fri Dec 01 2023 00:00:00 +0530 (IST)"))
```